# combobox rightclick file deletion (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, combobox, right-click

Im trying to delete an item from a combobox ussing a rightclick event but i can seam to get the code for it

what I do have is the following:

```
        Private Sub combobox1_RightClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.RightClick
Dim DELETEITEM as string= combobox1.text
        System.IO.File.Delete( "C:\" & DELETEITEM & ".txt" )
MsgBox("File Deleted")
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to delete the file with that name, try this:

```
   Private Sub combobox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles combobox1.MouseDown
       If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
            Dim DELETEITEM as string= combobox1.text
            Kill("C:\" & DELETEITEM & ".txt")
            MsgBox("File Deleted")
        End if
    End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error ststing Error 1 Event 'RightClick' cannot be found?

Comment: Oh, sorry! Forgot about the right click! I edited my code, so try that way.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched for an answer to the same question to no avail. I have however used the following workaround. Instead of using right click event, it runs a different procedure if you hold down the Ctrl Button and left click. Not perfect but it works.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Try
            If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown Then
              ' run function a using ComboBox1 selected item
            Else
              ' run function b using ComboBox1 selected item
            End If

        Catch
             add err handler
        End Try

    End Sub
```